# User Managed Identity - how to authenticate using c#

Tags: azure-managed-identity

Is there an example of how to authenticate azure resource using User Managed Identity using c#? I am using the following code to authenticate using system managed identity and it works fine. but not sure about how to pass the user managed identity resource in the following example.

```
 AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

        KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
        var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("https://mykeyvaultname.vault.azure.net/secrets/test")
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        return new string[] { secret.Value };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the documentation [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/windowsvm-msi-arm-dotnet#running-the-application-using-a-user-assigned-managed-identity-in-azure-vm). This feature is in the 1.2.0-preview version of the library. It only works on Azure VMs and VMSS as of now. You need to set the client id in a connection string, which can either be specified in the constructor or in the env variable (documentation of other connection string options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#connection-string-support)). In this scenario, the constructor is recommended, so you can use developer identity/ cert for local and switch to the user-assigned identity on Azure.

Update: The library has been updated to support user assigned identity in App Services as well as part of 1.2.0-preview2.

Comment: May I ask why this is the place where this is documented? Shouldn't this be clearly documents on learn.microsoft.com and in the example GitHub repository? 

Based on the documentation I found in the above places I thought User Assigned Identities were good to go in Azure App Service when they are clearly not.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I will get the documentation updated, and get back on this thread.